# PF 11.0.0: which mojarra versions are supported?

Tags: primefaces, mojarra

PF 11.0.0: which mojarra versions are supported?
It is not specified in pom.xml. The showcase used to show the mojarra version, but not now.

Comment: See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/gettingstarted/dependencies) PrimeFaces 11 has dependency JSF with ver. 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0. Where JSF can be Apache MyFaces or Eclipse (former Oracle) Mojarra.